# LatLng return 0,0

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

I am trying to create an app that shows my current location
I have all the permisson neccessary,
I have another class name GPS tracker to get my gps locations

Heres my code :

```
GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(this);
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
latitude = gpsTracker.latitude;
longitude = gpsTracker.longitude;
LatLng latLng = new  LatLng(latitude, longitude);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));
```

Here is the GPSTracker class:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: run your app in device.. in emulator always shows 0,0

Comment: Are you trying in real device???

Comment: yes I'm trying on my tablet :S The thing is it used to work before just fine. I closed my laptop and opened it next morning and it started giving 0,0 cannot figure out why :S

Comment: It isn't working for two reasons.  First is you don't have a GPS lock yet.  Second, because the class sucks so badly we get multiple questions about it every week.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DO NOT USE THE GPS TRACKER CLASS.  It's horribly horribly broken.  In so many ways I wrote a long blog post about it tonight:  see http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Here's the ways its broken:

1)It doesn't track GPS.  Sometimes it tracks network location instead

2)The canGetLocation function is broken.  It returns true before it has a location

3)Its horribly inefficient, forcing you to poll.

4)It doesn't differentiate stale from fresh data-  and doesn't let you do it either

I'd go on but I already wrote it up tonight.

I wrote a much better GPS tracker library at my blog.  Here it is repeated for SO use

LocationTracker.java

```
package com.gabesechan.android.reusable.location;

import android.location.Location;

public interface LocationTracker {
    public interface LocationUpdateListener{
        public void onUpdate(Location oldLoc, long oldTime, Location newLoc, long newTime);
    }

    public void start();
    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update);

    public void stop();

    public boolean hasLocation();

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation();

    public Location getLocation();

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation();

}
```

ProviderLocationTracker.java

```
package com.gabesechan.android.reusable.location;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ProviderLocationTracker implements LocationListener, LocationTracker {

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE = 10; 

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_UPDATE_TIME = 1000 * 60; 

    private LocationManager lm;

    public enum ProviderType{
        NETWORK,
        GPS
    };    
    private String provider;

    private Location lastLocation;
    private long lastTime;

    private boolean isRunning;

    private LocationUpdateListener listener;

    public ProviderLocationTracker(Context context, ProviderType type) {
        lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(type == ProviderType.NETWORK){
            provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        }
        else{
            provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            //Already running, do nothing
            return;
        }

        //The provider is on, so start getting updates.  Update current location
        isRunning = true;
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE, this);
        lastLocation = null;
        lastTime = 0;
        return;
    }

    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update) {
        start();
        listener = update;

    }


    public void stop(){
        if(isRunning){
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            isRunning = false;
            listener = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(){
        if(lastLocation == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 5 * MIN_UPDATE_TIME){
            return false; //stale
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        if(lastLocation != null){
            return true;
        }
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider)!= null;
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        if(lastLocation == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime > 5 * MIN_UPDATE_TIME){
            return null; //stale
        }
        return lastLocation;
    }

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        if(lastLocation != null){
            return lastLocation;
        }
        return lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLoc) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onUpdate(lastLocation, lastTime, newLoc, now);
        }
        lastLocation = newLoc;
        lastTime = now;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    }




}
```

FallbackLocationTracker.java

```
package com.gabesechan.android.reusable.location;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class FallbackLocationTracker  implements LocationTracker, LocationTracker.LocationUpdateListener {


    private boolean isRunning;

    private ProviderLocationTracker gps;
    private ProviderLocationTracker net;

    private LocationUpdateListener listener;

    Location lastLoc;
    long lastTime;

    public FallbackLocationTracker(Context context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType type) {
        gps = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.GPS);
        net = new ProviderLocationTracker(context, ProviderLocationTracker.ProviderType.NETWORK);
    }

    public void start(){
        if(isRunning){
            //Already running, do nothing
            return;
        }

        //Start both
        gps.start(this);
        net.start(this);
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public void start(LocationUpdateListener update) {
        start();
        listener = update;
    }


    public void stop(){
        if(isRunning){
            gps.stop();
            net.stop();
            isRunning = false;
            listener = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasLocation(){
        //If either has a location, use it
        return gps.hasLocation() || net.hasLocation();
    }

    public boolean hasPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        //If either has a location, use it
        return gps.hasPossiblyStaleLocation() || net.hasPossiblyStaleLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation(){
        Location ret = gps.getLocation();
        if(ret == null){
            ret = net.getLocation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public Location getPossiblyStaleLocation(){
        Location ret = gps.getPossiblyStaleLocation();
        if(ret == null){
            ret = net.getPossiblyStaleLocation();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void onUpdate(Location oldLoc, long oldTime, Location newLoc, long newTime) {
        boolean update = false;

        //We should update only if there is no last location, the provider is the same, or the provider is more accurate, or the old location is stale
        if(lastLoc == null){
            update = true;
        }
        else if(lastLoc != null && lastLoc.getProvider().equals(newLoc.getProvider())){
            update = true;
        }
        else if(newLoc.getProvider().equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            update = true;
        }
        else if (newTime - lastTime > 5 * 60 * 1000){
            update = true;
        }

        if(update){
            lastLoc = newLoc;
            lastTime = newTime;
            if(listener != null){
                listener.onUpdate(lastLoc, lastTime, newLoc, newTime);                  
            }
        }

    }


}
```

The interface defines a generic location tracker so you can switch between them.  ProviderLocationTracker will allow you to track via GPS or network, depending on the parameter you pass to its constructor.  FallbackLocationTracker will track via both, giving you only the most accurate info currently available but falling back to network if GPS isn't ready.

Comment: Hey @Gabe Sechan How to use it?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan from where exactly I can get _latitude_ and _longitude_ with _String_ s?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I try use Your code? but on ProviderLocationTracker.java I have error  `lm.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_UPDATE_TIME, MIN_UPDATE_DISTANCE, this);` requires permission. I write `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)` but have error  in `this` argument. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: @Gabe Sechan can you please provide code or any demo for implementation of your classes??

Answer (score 0):

use this code

and implemets your activity from "implements LocationListener"

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,3000,   // 3 sec
        5, this);
  boolean isGPS = locationManager.isProviderEnabled (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  if(!isGPS)
    {
        showSettingsAlert();
        GPS_imageview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gpsnonfix);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Start GPS to get more Accurate location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
    }
```

and use following also

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {



    int a=location.getExtras().getInt("satellites") ;





    if(a>4)
    {



        String str = "Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" \nLongitude: "+location.getLongitude();
    //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Double lat=location.getLatitude();
        Double lan=location.getLongitude();


    }else{

    }




    String str = "Latitude: "+location.getLatitude()+" \nLongitude: "+location.getLongitude();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    /******** Called when User off Gps *********/

   Latitude="0.0";
        Longitude="0.0";
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned off ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    /******** Called when User on Gps  *********/

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Gps turned on ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This code get no of sattelite .if no of sattelite is greter than 4 then get proper result..thats accuracy of result is good...

Answer (score 0):

When you start your app, your GPS probably has not yet made connection and gives you a default location such as 0,0. If your phone finds its coordinates at a later point in time, your app has no way of detecting this.

This line:

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

states that every time your phone discovers a change of location, the "OnLocationChanged"-method (of the object in which you called that line of code), is called. As far as I can see, you did not implement this method yet.

I suggest the following. Change your third line to:
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsTracker);

So it uses the implementation of the onLocationChanged method of your gpsTracker.
Now, implement the OnLocationChanged-method of the GPSTracker-class which you already defined, but not yet implemented:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     //This method is triggered every time your location changes. 
     //The 'location' argument can be used to access the current location.
}
```