# Calculating walking distance (Android)

Tags: java, android, geolocation, gps, distance

I'm trying to calculate  running route distance for fitness application 
I tried to find my current location then after 5 seconeds find new location, calculate distance and then sum them all after that swipe the current location to the previous location and update new current location but I think that it always takes the same location and the distance stay at 0.

Here sample of the code-

```
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //location is the location of user
            PrvLoc = new Location(MyLoc);
            MyLoc = new Location(location);
            Toast.makeText(Running_Activity.this, "" + location.getLatitude() + " , " + location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Distance += PrvLoc.distanceTo(location);
            d.setText("" + Distance+" Km");
            s.setText("" + MyLoc.getSpeed()+" Km/h");
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LatLng return 0,0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627745/latlng-return-0-0)

Answer (score 0):

The is going to be a bad way of implementing this functionality.  GPS is just too noisy and inaccurate.  When you sum up inaccurate values, your end result is more inaccurate than the individual values.  Doing this over the length of a few miles is just going to be nothing remotely related to the actual length traveled.

You can do this of course, but you're either going to have to implement a lot of smoothing, or incorporate another source of data, such as a step count.